# Is Piwik Pro a fork of Matomo?

Tags: analytics, privacy, open-source, matomo

[Piwik PRO](https://piwik.pro/) is web analytics software that is compatible with [CNIL's recommendations](https://www.cnil.fr/fr/cookies-et-autres-traceurs/regles/cookies-solutions-pour-les-outils-de-mesure-daudience).

Piwik PRO is a Polish company which originally run on the open-source software Piwik; the project later renamed to [Matomo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matomo_(software)).

However, I noticed that the [Piwik PRO repository](https://github.com/PiwikPRO/PiwikPRO) was last updated 4 years ago. To me, it sounds like the service is either running on old code, or it is now running on a proprietary software.

Can anyone confirm if Piwik PRO is running on new proprietary software? If not, is it derived from the old Matomo code or the current Matomo source code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: The question (as originally written) falls under "Website management" and doesn't fall under any of the offtopic categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We started as a company that monetized Piwik (now Matomo), but at some point in time we realized that PHP+MySQL monolithic architecture of Piwik is not going to cut it for high volume customers. We split from the community and started developing a proprietary analytics engine based on ClickHouse - [here's more](https://piwik.pro/piwik-pro-vs-matomo-comparison/#chapter-3). [This is our changelog](https://piwik.pro/changelog/), we release every 2 weeks.

There's nothing in the platform that runs on Matomo source code. We stopped contributing/sponsoring the open-source Piwik around the time we split in 2016; [quite visible on this chart](https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/graphs/contributors).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've read that page before but it wasn't clear to me that Piwik PRO is a complete rewrite. It would be useful in my opinion to clarify that it's fully nonfree and incompatible with Matomo, for those who might incorrectly expect the availability of a migration path from Piwiki PRO to Matomo or the ability to modify some part of the software, as you can do in open core.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. For complete clarity: we've a backwards compatibility with Matomo tracker, so you can send the events to Piwik PRO without changing much to your analytics setup on site. We also migrate historical data for our enterprise customers.